# rich:fileUpload loses elements after page refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using the rich faces element `rich:fileUpload`. File upload works fine.

I just think that one behavior is relay problematic:
The User uploades the files. He can now see all the files he has uploaded and clear one or all files if necessary. However, if he refreshes the page (F5 or some shortcut), the filelist is cleared. All the other information in the form are present, but not the list of the uploaded files. What is even worse: the user has now no possibility to delete a once uploaded file.

Is there a way to show the file render/load the filelist inside the `fileUpload` element again. I could easily make a `dataGrid` but is seems wrong to present the filelist two times, just in case the user refreshed the page.

The rich faces showcase also uses a second list: [fileUpload-Demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload)

Comment: You will need to put your bean SessionScoped...

Comment: Wonder why it is not answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the demo [fileUpload-Demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload), they are using *@SessionScoped* bean. When using *@RequestScoped* or *@ViewScoped* bean, the bean is recreated since the view is.

This will be the easiest way to fix your problem.